# jquery - fancybox - Syntax error with URLs starting with '/'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox 2.0.6 and jQuery 1.7.2 and when I use a href url that begins with a slash, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /path/to/load
```

If I remove the slash, it works. Obviously, I get a 404, but fancybox opens.

And yes, I do need the url to start with a slash.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you include some JS code that triggers the error?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem in jQuery 1.7.1 with Fancybox 2.0.5.

Not only the slash at beginning,
also a letter "a" or one or more dot before the slash cause the same problem in my test.
It seems that typing other letters or more letter "a" is work fine.

I solve it by using **absolute paths** in "href" attributes.
Another solution, you can try the "href" option for Fancybox. ([document](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs))

I have try it and found that using `$(this).attr('href')` could work fine,
even the paths are relative and begin with slashes.

The code I tried:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    href: $(this).attr('href')
});
```

Updated on July 3, 2012:

I found that the code I tried above is not always work, and made some demos [here](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/290#issuecomment-6735140).
It seems no error when using the "type" option.

Answer (score 1):

You must add this property to your link: data-fancybox-type="iframe"

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread but still higher up on Google. You can review the bug submitted on Github for Fancybox:

https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/290

> Note! If fancyBox will not be able to get content type, error message
>   will be displayed (this is different from previsous versions where
>   'ajax' was used as default type).

That means you will need to speficy the type of request ('ajax', 'iframe', 'inline'):

ex:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
     type: 'ajax'
});
```

or

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
     type: $.support.ajax? 'ajax':'iframe'
});
```